# Are the ex-parasites in Darling in the FranXX immortal?

Tags: darling-in-the-franxx

In the final episode of the anime, Nana and Hachi (who used to be parasites in the past) claim that they're immortal:

> **We don't age** and we're stuck in the middle, neither adults nor children. We have but one duty: to reach out to humanity's future and continue to watch over it. ~Hachi

But just a few minutes later the conversation between Futoshi and Ikuno seems to contradict it:

> It's all thanks to your research that us ex-parasites' **accelerated aging** is being kept in check. ~Futoshi

What information have I missed? Are ex-parasites immortal or mortal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between parasites and adults. It's known that adults don't age anymore because of APE. Since Nana and Hachi worked for APE we can conclude that their technology to make people immortal was also used on them.

Consequently, every parasite can become immortal. But in the last episode the ex-parasites decided to stop using magma energy which is necessary for achieving immortality. Since these people, being clones, age faster than humans, Ikuno was desperately trying to find a cure for that accelerated aging.

While not being able to find a complete cure for that condition, she still finally found a way to keep it in check which is more than enough for the affected people to live a normal life.

Comment: Aren't the parasites synthetic children? If I remember correctly they are actually clones and also contained a bit of blood (or DNA) from Klaxosaurs. So, if that's correct, these children should be fundamentally different from the adults. And what do you mean with "normal life"? Do they age like humans used to or are do you refer to their way of life which finally has become that of humans and not parasites?

Comment: I was referring to latter. Since nobody is able to reproduce other than Dr. Franxx possibly, all the parasites are synthetic. They either die while fighting or aging faster than humans. However since they stopped using Franxxs that aging slowed a bit. Also from what we see in last ep thanks to Ikuno she slows that aging process a bit more. We dont know how though. Another rushed part of the show sadly.

Comment: So, deriving from your answer is it correct to say that firstly, parasites, being clones, age faster than humans in general and operating the Franxx reduces their life expectancy even more, and secondly, magma energy is a necessity for achieving immortality?

Comment: Btw., concerning Ikuno trying to find a "cure": wouldn't it be correct to say that she was trying to find a countermeasure rather than a cure? I mean, parasites are, if I'm not wrong, born with a reduced life expectancy. If that's true then Ikuno's goal has always been to keep that accelerated aging in check which she also finally achieves (you can't call it a cure if that living being is being born with the supposed disease). So, she does reach her goal.

Comment: Well you see its about perspective. You can cure someone even if said person has that disease when they born however why I am using the word cure? Well because for the characters in the show even slowing it/keeping in check is a cure or at least that's the impression I got.